# Restricting a plotted expression to reals in a Manipuate

Tags: plotting, manipulate, assumptions

I have an expression from which I'm trying to create a plot that I can manipulate. The expression contains `Abs`, and I only want to have it evaluated for reals. What happens when I manipulate the plot is that it is appears to render even when `Abs` is taking on a complex value, which is something I want to prevent.

Is there a way to restrict the rendering only when a Real number is produced, and ... I don't know ... show a blank plot otherwise.

#### EDIT

example function

```
e1 = Abs[Sqrt[delta*Cos[theta] - b]]
e1 // Manipulate[Plot[#, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}], {b, 0, 2}, {delta, 0, 2}] &
```

Comment: Dan, Would you include some code so we know the specific function you are working with?

Comment: David, I can do that, but the function is fairly hairy... and I don't know how to reduce it to a point where it still illustrates the problem.

Comment: I updated the question with a simplified function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Abs[Sqrt[e]]` automatically simplifies to `Sqrt[Abs[e]]`.  Perhaps the easiest way is to define a real absolute value:

```
abs[x_Real] := If[x < 0, -x, x];
e1 = abs[Sqrt[delta*Cos[theta] - b]]
e1 // Manipulate[Plot[#, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}], {b, 0, 2}, {delta, 0, 2}] &
```

---

*Edit:*

While the above `abs` works perfectly with `Plot`, where the argument `x` is always `Real`, the following works in more general situations:

```
abs[x_?(Element[#, Reals] &)] := If[x < 0, -x, x];
```

Note the common solution `abs[x_?NumericQ]` doesn't work with the `Manipulate`.  It generates a `Less::nord` message about an invalid comparison with a complex number on some inputs.